# Show that $\textbf y \in R(A)$ is a linear combination of $\lbrace \textbf u \rbrace$

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-verification

I am trying to show that any $\textbf y \in R(A)$ is a linear combination of $\lbrace \textbf u \rbrace$ where $\textbf v \in \text R^q$ and $\textbf u \in \text R^p$ and $A = \textbf u \textbf v^T$. This is part of the proof where I try to show that $\textbf u $ is a basis of $R(A)$ (Note: $R(A) = \lbrace A\textbf x : \textbf x \in \text R^q\rbrace$).

So far the closest I have gotten is to say that any $\textbf y \in R(A)$ implies that $\textbf y \in \text R^q$ and that $A \textbf y = \textbf u \textbf v^T \textbf y = \alpha \textbf u$ where $\alpha \in \text R$. I don't think that shows the claim though. I think it just says that $A \textbf y$ is a linear combination of $\textbf u$. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're proving it right but you're taking the wrong notations. $\forall y \in R(A), y=Ax$. This means that $y=uv^{T}x$ and hence all $y\text{s}$ are linear combinations of $u$. The step where you're going wrong is taking that $y \in \mathbb{R}^{q}$. Actually $y$ is in the range space and hence $y \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and it is $x$ that is in $\mathbb{R}^{q}$. Note that the dimensions of $A$ is $p \times q$ and not $q \times p$.

Comment: So my understanding was that if $\textbf y \in R(A)$ then that implied that $\textbf y \in \text R^q$ such that $A \textbf y$ (So straight from the definition of $R(A)$). But you are saying that if $\textbf y \in R(A)$ then that implies that $\textbf y \in \text R^p$ such that $A \textbf x = \textbf y$ , correct?

Comment: You've understood the mapping wrongly here. $A$ maps anything in $\mathbb{R}^q$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$. If that's the case then how can $y \in \mathbb{R}^q$if $y=Ax$?